# Split string by commas ignoring any punctuation marks (including ',') in quotation marks

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

How can I split string (from a textbox) by commas *excluding* those in double quotation marks (*without getting rid of the quotation marks*), along with other possible punctuation marks (e.g. ' . ' ' ; ' ' - ')?

E.g. If someone entered the following into the textbox:

```
apple, orange, "baboons, cows", rainbow, "unicorns, gummy bears"
```

How can I split the above string into the following (say, into a List)?

```
apple

orange

"baboons, cows"

rainbow

"Unicorns, gummy bears..."
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If processing CSV files, it's better to use an existing library, such as LinqToCSV (there are others as well), rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Thank you @hatchet for your suggestion, but I'm actually trying to ask the user for search terms (to query a database).

Comment: Note: space is not a punctuation mark, but your expected results drop the space too. Don't forget about that in your code. And at least one of the current answers assumes that *every* comma will be followed by a space, and actually splits on `", "`. Beware that this does not work for `apple,orange`. Also, how should `apple,orange"banana,peach"almond,kiwi` be split, when `"` does not appear anywhere near a comma?

Comment: Or... since you say this is for search terms, why require the user to type commas at all? Will the user expect that searching for `a b c` searches for that exact phrase, and the user has to type `a, b, c` instead to search for those words? It depends on the user; you should probably double-check that this is indeed what your users expect, or change the logic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions and advice, @hvd!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the below regex which uses positive lookahead,

```
string value = @"apple, orange, ""baboons, cows"", rainbow, ""unicorns, gummy bears""";
string[] lines = Regex.Split(value, @", (?=(?:""[^""]*?(?: [^""]*)*))|, (?=[^"",]+(?:,|$))");

foreach (string line in lines) {
Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

**Output:**

```
apple
orange
"baboons, cows"
rainbow
"unicorns, gummy bears"
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/R5tt0Z)

Comment: if you want to split according to `,.:-` then use a character class `[,.:-] (?=(?:""[^""]*?(?: [^""]*)*))|[,.:-] (?=[^"",]+(?:,|$))`

Comment: No worries, @Avinash. I was trying on all of these nice suggestions to see which one is more suitable in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Regex str = new Regex("(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

foreach (Match m in str.Matches(input))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value.TrimStart(','));
}
```

You may also try to look at [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/)

Comment: Thank you @R.T. but it only works if the quotation mark is immediately after a comma (i.e. not separated by a space). Sorry but I'm not familiar with regex!

Answer (score 1):

Much like a CSV parser, instead of Regex, you can loop through each character, like so:

```
public List<string> ItemStringToList(string inputString)
{  
    var itemList   = new List<string>();
    var currentIem = "";
    var quotesOpen = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.Length; i++)
    {
        if (inputString[i] == '"')
        {
            quotesOpen = !quotesOpen;
            continue;
        }

        if (inputString[i] == ',' && !quotesOpen)
        {
            itemList.Add(currentIem);
            currentIem = "";
            continue;
        }

        if (currentIem == "" && inputString[i] == ' ') continue;
        currentIem += inputString[i];
    }

    if (currentIem != "") itemList.Add(currentIem);

    return itemList;
}
```

Example test usage:

```
var test1 = ItemStringToList("one, two, three");
var test2 = ItemStringToList("one, \"two\", three");
var test3 = ItemStringToList("one, \"two, three\"");
var test4 = ItemStringToList("one, \"two, three\", four, \"five six\", seven");
var test5 = ItemStringToList("one, \"two, three\", four, \"five six\", seven");
var test6 = ItemStringToList("one, \"two, three\", four, \"five six, seven\"");
var test7 = ItemStringToList("\"one, two, three\", four, \"five six, seven\"");
```

You could change it to use StringBuilder if you want faster character joining.

Comment: Nice one. BTW: I'd use an [iterator method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) and `yield` instead of `itemList.Add`. That would allow you to get rid of `itemList` (less code) and have deferred execution for free as an additional benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this it will work u c an split array string in many waysif you want to split by white space just put a space in (' ') .

```
  namespace LINQExperiment1
  {
  class Program
  {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   string[] sentence = new string[] { "apple", "orange", "baboons  cows", " rainbow", "unicorns  gummy bears" };

  Console.WriteLine("option 1:"); Console.WriteLine("————-");
  // option 1: Select returns three string[]’s with
  // three strings in each.
  IEnumerable<string[]> words1 =
  sentence.Select(w => w.Split(' '));
  // to get each word, we have to use two foreach loops
  foreach (string[] segment in words1)
  foreach (string word in segment)
  Console.WriteLine(word);
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine("option 2:"); Console.WriteLine("————-");
  // option 2: SelectMany returns nine strings
  // (sub-iterates the Select result)
  IEnumerable<string> words2 =
  sentence.SelectMany(segment => segment.Split(','));
  // with SelectMany we have every string individually
  foreach (var word in words2)
  Console.WriteLine(word);
  // option 3: identical to Opt 2 above written using
  // the Query Expression syntax (multiple froms)
  IEnumerable<string> words3 =from segment in sentence
  from word in segment.Split(' ')
  select word;
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: @MooMooCoding Welcome =D

Answer (score 0):

This was trickier than I thought, a good practical problem I think.

Below is the solution I came up with for this. One thing I don't like about my solution is having to add double quotations back and the other one being names of the variables :p:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string searchString =
            @"apple, orange, ""baboons, cows. dogs- hounds"", rainbow, ""unicorns, gummy bears"", abc, defghj";

        char delimeter = ',';
        char excludeSplittingWithin = '"';

        string[] splittedByExcludeSplittingWithin = searchString.Split(excludeSplittingWithin);

        List<string> splittedSearchString = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < splittedByExcludeSplittingWithin.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || splittedByExcludeSplittingWithin[i].StartsWith(delimeter.ToString()))
            {
                string[] splitttedByDelimeter = splittedByExcludeSplittingWithin[i].Split(delimeter);
                for (int j = 0; j < splitttedByDelimeter.Length; j++)
                {
                    splittedSearchString.Add(splitttedByDelimeter[j].Trim());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                splittedSearchString.Add(excludeSplittingWithin + splittedByExcludeSplittingWithin[i] +
                                         excludeSplittingWithin);
            }
        }

        foreach (string s in splittedSearchString)
        {
            if (s.Trim() != string.Empty)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, @HakuKalay. It's nice and rather rewarding to see different people's approach to the same problem. The theory behind some of the solutions can also be used in tackling other kinds of problems!

Answer (score 0):

Another Regex solution:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Parse(string input)
{
  // if used frequently, should be instantiated with Compiled option
  Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=^|,\s)(\""(?:[^\""]|\""\"")*\""|[^,\s]*)");

  return regex.Matches(inputData).Where(m => m.Success);
}
```