# python pandas read_csv quotechar does not work

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743479/pandas-read-csv-with-extra-commas-in-column), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595819/double-quoted-elements-in-csv-cant-read-with-pandas) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686920/reading-csv-from-pandas-having-both-quotechar-and-delimiter-for-a-column-value) posts but despite I don't know why `quotechar` does not work at `pd.read_csv()` (Python 3, pandas 0.18.0 and 0.18.1). And how could I read a dataframe like this:

```
"column1","column2", "column3", "column4", "column5", "column6"
"AM", 7, "1", "SD", "SD", "CR"
"AM", 8, "1,2 ,3", "PR, SD,SD", "PR ; , SD,SD", "PR , ,, SD ,SD"
"AM", 1, "2", "SD", "SD", "SD"
```

I want the following result:

```
Out[116]: 
  column1  column2 column3    column4       column5        column6
0      AM        7       1         SD            SD             CR
1      AM        8  1,2 ,3  PR, SD,SD  PR ; , SD,SD  PR , ,, SD,SD
2      AM        1       2         SD            SD             SD
```

Thank you!!

Comment: pd.read_csv('test.csv',sep=',\s+')

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I wrote, I read the linked post so I tried this solution too, but does not work. I get this error messages: `ValueError: Expected 6 fields in line 3, saw 10`. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Pandas doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table) on separators in `read_csv()`:

> Separators longer than 1 character and different from '\s+' will be
>   interpreted as regular expressions, will force use of the python
>   parsing engine and will ignore quotes in the data.

Try using this instead (`sep` by default set to a comma):

```
pd.read_csv(file, skipinitialspace = True, quotechar = '"')
```

Comment: The important bit for me was `skipinitialspace = True` which ignores the space between the delimiters. The 'Error' in OPs CSV File is the space between commas, which is - apparently - not typical for csv.

Comment: That does not work for me, pandas==0.22.0. My separator is ";", does this make a difference? should it?

Comment: @RicardoMS Have you tried it with `sep=';'`, that is `pd.read_csv(file, skipinitialspace=True, quotechar='"', sep=';')`?

Comment: @ptrj thanks! I found the problem, I needed to add `escapechar='\\'` argument. My file was very "dirty". Thanks a lot for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a proper regular expression instead of the simple `\s+`. We need to find comma (`,`) which is not within quotation marks:

```
pd.read_csv(file, 
            sep=', (?=(?:"[^"]*?(?: [^"]*)*))|, (?=[^",]+(?:,|$))',
            engine='python')
```

The expression is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471521/split-string-by-commas-ignoring-any-punctuation-marks-including-in-quotati/25471762#25471762).