# pandas read csv - recognize entries in quotation marks while using space delimiter?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to read in text files that look like this with pandas:

```
Flag Rootname "Target Name" RA DEC PropID "PI Name" Detector Segment LP Grating Cenwave FPPOS Exptime Nevents "Mean Flux" "Median Flux" Date "Target Description"
1 lcjw02hwq RXJ2043.1+0324 310.7761535644531 3.4143054485321045 13840 Fox FUV BOTH 2 G130M 1291 2 2935.199951171875 1472553.0 4.113247049008454e-15 3.6400732688485204e-15 2014-10-23 "ISM;ABSORPTION LINE SYSTEM;HIGH VELOCITY CLOUD"
1 lcjw02ikq RXJ2043.1+0324 310.7761535644531 3.4143054485321045 13840 Fox FUV BOTH 2 G130M 1291 4 1375.199951171875 769373.0 4.134839189383387e-15 3.562496062308341e-15 2014-10-23 "ISM;ABSORPTION LINE SYSTEM;HIGH VELOCITY CLOUD"
```

Each new term or value is separated by a space, but the issue is that some of these are in quotation marks and also have spaces inside. For example `"Target Name"` should be the name of one column, and `"ISM;ABSORPTION LINE SYSTEM;HIGH VELOCITY CLOUD"` is one value (although I do not need to store these with the quotation marks).

I tried the below code using `quotechar` as an input, but it does not work.

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\s', quotechar='"')
```

I also saw [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074914/python-pandas-read-csv-quotechar-does-not-work), but the suggestion of adding `skipinitialspace = True` as an argument did not help either. When I call `df.head()`, I can still see that it is splitting "Target Name", etc into two separate column names. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the `sep='\s'` to `sep=' '`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('<your file>', sep=' ', quotechar='"')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Flag   Rootname  ...        Date                              Target Description
0     1  lcjw02hwq  ...  2014-10-23  ISM;ABSORPTION LINE SYSTEM;HIGH VELOCITY CLOUD
1     1  lcjw02ikq  ...  2014-10-23  ISM;ABSORPTION LINE SYSTEM;HIGH VELOCITY CLOUD

[2 rows x 19 columns]
```

---

`df.to_csv()` produces then (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked! Just curious - do you know why '\s' did not work here?